# Json to url encoding ruby

Tags: ruby, json, url, uri, url-encoding

Trying to use URI library to generate JSON in the proper formate for Eventbrite batch endpoint but not getting the right encoding from URI library.

```
url = URI.escape('{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"users/me"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"users/me/owned_events/"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"users/me/owned_events/?page=2"}')

=>%7B%22method%22:%22GET%22,%20%22relative_url%22:%22users/me%22%7D,
%7B%22method%22:%22GET%22,%20%22relative_url%22:%22users/me/owned_events/%22%7D,
%7B%22method%22:%22GET%22,%20%22relative_url%22:%22users/me/owned_events/?page=2%22%7D
```

This is the require encoding:

```
%5B+++++%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C+%22relative_url%22%3A%22users%2Fme
%22%7D%2C+++++%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C+%22relative_url%22%3A
%22users%2Fme%2Fowned_events%2F%22%7D%2C+++++%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET
%22%2C+%22relative_url%22%3A%22users%2Fme%2Fowned_events%2F%3Fpage%3D2%22%7D+%5D
```

Comment: These look exactly the same with `CGI.escape` and `CGI.unescape`, only the "required encoding" has spaces and newlines. Are you sure this is the source of whatever problem you are experiencing? It might very well not be..

Comment: I am sure this is the source as I have tried requests with the required encoding successfully you can try the api here:  https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/batch/

Comment: I can't use the link since I don't have a token. However, I believe you need to send a POST request, not a GET request, so encoding using URI.escape is not something you need to be doing. The URI endpoint should simply be `eventbriteapi.com/v3/batch`, and you should submit the array of JSONs via POST.

Comment: Oh, you forgot to enclose your JSON objects in an Array... `CGI.escape('[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"users/me"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"users/me/owned_events/"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"users/me/owned_events/?page=2"}]')` looks much more similar to your desired outcome.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you forgot to enclose your JSON objects in an array (note the square brackets):

> CGI.escape('[{"method":"GET",
>   "relative_url":"users/me"},{"method":"GET",
>   "relative_url":"users/me/owned_events/"},{"method":"GET",
>   "relative_url":"users/me/owned_events/?page=2"}]')

Results in:

> %5B%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C+%22relative_url%22%3A%22users%2Fme%22%7D%2C%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C+%22relative_url%22%3A%22users%2Fme%2Fowned_events%2F%22%7D%2C%7B%22method%22%3A%22GET%22%2C+%22relative_url%22%3A%22users%2Fme%2Fowned_events%2F%3Fpage%3D2%22%7D%5D

Which is the same as your desired outcome, give or take white spaces.

I'm not sure why you're using URI for this, by the way. The URI should simply be `eventbriteapi.com/v3/batch` as far as I understand. Based on their [documentation](https://www.eventbrite.com/developer/v3/reference/batching/), it seems like the payload you're sending should be sent to this URI via a POST request. For encoding of payloads you should use `CGI` or `Base64`.